# Display a popup from calendar view when selecting a date

Tags: java, android, calendar, popup

Im working with a calendar view in android studio and I would like to have it perform like in the picture below. Basically, displaying a popup when a date is selected:

[Here's a picture of my blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuz7K.jpg)

So I wonder if there is any possible way to achieve this with the CalendarView, especially with text + button inside the popup, with X rows inside the popup menu.

EDIT:

So, I'm not sure that my first image-link did work. But I hope this one works.

I want like this menu, to display when user clicks on a date.
Also, I would like to have that menu scrollable.

**PICTURE:** https://ibb.co/QNbbgPX

Comment: You need to create a customized calender for this . There is already bunch of third party implementation available on Git if you wanna use one .

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know some that can accomplish what I want to accomplish? Or could you provide a link for this?

Comment: The popup thing you need to create yourself rest you can get already implemented . Just search for it

Comment: Haha so why are you commenting then? I clearly asked for help about the popup thing didn't I? Of course I already been searching without success for this otherwise why would I be here asking?

Comment: No need for HAHA here . your question is way too broad . I'm just helping .

Comment: Ok, but which part in my question didn't you understand? I mean, when you click on the date, I would like to have that popup/popdown menu so the ui displays some options to choose between.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you need to use `OnDateChangeListener` the event will be triggered when you click on a day and an `AlertDialog` with your layout to show :

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new 

        AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
        AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
})
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! I'll give you a heads up when I tried it out.

Comment: Perfect! You understood what my goal was. This works like a charm, but I'm not sure that you did check the image that I included in the post? I would like to have like a dropdown of the button click on the selected date. Now there's a normal popup which in fact would work great, but not really what I was aiming for. Can you confirm that the image-link in my main-post works?

Comment: That type of popup menu is called contextual menu (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#context-menu) I tried to use it on calendar but it won't work sorry.

Comment: I finally got it to work, I believe I were a little to broad with the question maybe, or even very unclear. So, I got it to work with a dropdown-menu. Now, I wonder if there's any way of controlling where the dropdownmenu displays, depending on which date in the calendar view I select? I.e. if you choose a date top left corner, then a date in right down corner, the menu appears in top left always.

Comment: Logi95 did you find any solution?